# PHP MYSQLI two queries in a page

Tags: php, mysqli, include

I have two php files. They each have a different query in them. Both of them work. Then I have one file where I include both files inside of it. The queries work on their individual pages, but in the page where they are both included only the first query works. They look something like this (The first one uses * because I pull out every row)

```
include 'connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER by jid DESC";

$ex = $mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($ex);

if ($row_cnt  > 0) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $ex->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["one"] . $row["two"] . $row["three"] . $row["four"];
    }


    $result->free();
}


$mysqli->close($mysqli);
```

The second one is like this

```
include 'connect.php';

$q = "SELECT one, three FROM table ORDER by jid DESC";

$d = $mysqli->query($q) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($d);

if ($row_cnt  > 0) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $d->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["one"] . $row["three"];
    }


    $result->free();
}


$mysqli->close($mysqli);
```

Then the file that includes them is just two includes like *include ' ';*

How do I get both queries to work on the one page?

Answer (score 0):

add value in array, like this:

```
include 'connect.php';

$q = "SELECT one, three FROM jokes ORDER by jid DESC";

$d = $mysqli->query($q) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($d);

$values = array();

if ($row_cnt  > 0) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $d->fetch_assoc()) {
        $values[0][] = $row["one"];
        $values[1][] = $row["two"];
        $values[2][] = $row["three"];
        $values[3][] = $row["four"];
    }


    $result->free();
}


$mysqli->close($mysqli);
```

... after, use `foreach` for print the value

*I have not tested*

Answer (score -1):

> How do I get both queries to work on the one page?

Just run them one after another like everyone does.

If something goes wrong - debug your code, like everyone does. Read all the error messages and act accordingly.

Comment: Uh, you're right. Knowledge should just appear in our heads right? How about be polite ----- like everyone should
Maybe suggest how to run them one after another..